# Cannot extrude curve after converting to mesh

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, extrude

So I drew a teardrop-shaped bezier curve and converted it to a mesh using `Object -> Convert to -> Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text`. A new mesh object appeared in my collection, but when I select it and go into Edit mode, `Mesh -> Extrude` has no options. Likewise, pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> just brings up a blank menu labeled "Extrude". What am I doing wrong here?

You can find my workflow [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSdbd.jpg).

Comment: It all worked fine here, except when I enter edit mode but the mesh is not select and the menu comes greyed out, also while using Face mode.

Comment: Hi @LeoNas, I've added a GIF to my post; hopefully that better illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Face selection mode.

Switch to Vertex or Edge mode to enable the first extrusion.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to extrude the edges of the curve, but it looks like a folded strip of paper. How can I fill in the shape?

Comment: Select the loop and use Mesh>Faces>Fill or Grid fill. The Grid fill is better.